# Buying wider wheels

Tags: wheels

I'm considering buying wider tires for my car. How do I find out the maximum width that would fit? Im currently running 205/50R16, if that indicates anything.

Comment: Also, the title says "wheels" and the body says "tires" ... are you looking to buy just wheels, just tires, or both? Not quite clear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for both rims and tires. It's a 2006 Mazda Miata Mx 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several considerations when going to wider than stock tires for a vehicle. The first consideration is, *how much tire can my rim handle?* In most cases, a rim can handle another ~20mm of tire width over the stock width. Once you go past this width, the tire will start bulging, will roll more in the corners, and aesthetically look terrible. All of this is contingent upon whether they will even physically be able to fit on the rims in the first place.

If you want to go past this rule of thumb, you'll need to get wider wheels to support the tire. Doing some reverse engineering with [this online calculator](http://www.tyresizecalculator.com/tyre-wheel-calculators/tyre-size-for-rim-size-width-calculator), your current wheel width is probably around 7" wide. The calculator states your tire width ranges are as follows for a 7" x 16" rim:

- Minimum tire width: 195mm
- Ideal tire width: 205-215mm
- Maximum tire width: 225mm

Each 10mm of tire width above that will require another 1/2" of rim width.

If you decide to get new rims to support even wider tires, you'll need to take into account the offset of the wheel, as well as the maximum width which will actually fit under your car without rubbing. This is too broad of a subject for an SE site, so will leave it at that. Your best bet is to research car forums which are dedicated to your specific car and see what they are using for those dimensions.